# Check formatting of text in Redactor

Tags: redactor

This is really a Redactor-specific question, but I wondered if there is a simple way for clients to view what H1, H2 etc. text is formatted as? I currently instruct them to click on the HTML button whilst selecting the text / having the cursor on the text to view what heading the text is, however it would be really nice for them to be able to see what the text is formatted as without having to look at HTML code.

This is the 2nd or 3rd client now that has asked me the same question. I wonder if anyone has experience in providing a cleaner solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Redactor setting that should do what you’re looking for:

> **Stucture**
>   This settings introduces visual indicators for HTML tags h1-h6 and div, helping users understand the structure of the document.

https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/special/#setting-structure

Example editor:
https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/structure/

Comment: I added: `"structure": true` to each config that I required to show what formatting is being used.